# mmap() in Linux - a part of the file vs the whole file

Tags: linux, file, mmap, memory-mapped-files

Would this statement be true or false? I was told conflicting information in regards to mmap() and now I am unsure.

A program can memory map only a part of file rather than the whole file in Linux using mmap().

Comment: Have you read `man mmap`?

Comment: What else would be the point of the `length` and `offset` parameters?

Comment: If you can't figure it out from the manual, why not build a simple program to try it?

Answer (score 0):

False -- a program can memory map part of a file, or the whole file.

Kind of a trick question, due to the confusing use of "only ... rather than", which is normally just used to emphasize things that are mutually exclusive.

This question perhaps belongs on https://english.stackexchange.com/ rather than here -- the question has little to do with mmap itself and more to do with the vagaries of English grammar.